# Prolog: How to adjust the maximum length of lists shown in a trace?

Tags: list, prolog, trace, prolog-toplevel

Feel free to cut immediately past the first two paragraphs, they are mostly waffle explaining the situation.

I'm working on a task for my University course, while I don't want any help solving the actual problem (I feel like that's "cheating" as it were) I would like help finding a way to extend the lengths of lists shown in prolog when tracing. For example, in the task you have to make a path finder through a maze with coloured "edges" between nodes which are each assigned a unique letter from the alphabet. The edges are "two way" and there is a "start" node that connects via a red edge to the "m" node also. The goal is to reach the "g" node in the middle while going along edges from the start in a repeating order of [red,brown,yellow].

Anyway, I think my algorithm finds a correct route at the bottom of the recursion, but going through the tracer is possible thousands of steps (I was holding return for about 2 minutes before it finished). Currently it doesn't "return" the generated list of steps (and while I'm sure some of you would be able to tell me how to do so, I'd rather you didn't because it's important I learn the actual prolog myself I feel) so the only time I see what's in the list of route steps is in the trace. **SO** here is the problem:

```
path(k, [red, brown, yellow], [[start, red], [m, brown], [e, yellow], [h, red], [r, brown], [p, yellow], [n|...], [...|...]|...], [start, m, e, h, r, p, n, j|...], g)
```

The final list holds the route I want to know if it's valid, however:

```
[start, m, e, h, r, p, n, j|...]
```

Cuts off at j, I want the trace to show FULL lists, otherwise I will have to go back through 100s of lines of trace trying to find the broken up and "correct" nodes in the path, with lots of backtracking mixed in i.e. really hard, and really easy to make a mistake. Also the I'm using program only keeps 30 or so lines prior (no idea if this is normal but I am using a SWI-Prolog(Multi-threaded, version 7.2.3) from the official site). Which means I'd have to go through everything past the first time it reaches the j node which would take a huge amount of time.

So as I say, this could be solved by having the list be unified (or whatever it is called) as a "return" (or whatever it is called) but I don't want an answer like that spoon fed to me and would rather figure it out on my own. So if you know how to do so, please refrain from telling me and just still with the way to increase the maximum displayed list with trace thank you.

I appreciate the help, sorry for the hoops I'm asking people to jump through.

Comment: Haha this comes up every couple of weeks here. See, [*Help: I want the whole answer*](http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/AllOutput.html).

Comment: Thank you. I think I can get that to work in the trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to prevent these kinds of outputs `[_|...]` adding the code below ;

```
:- set_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_options,
    [quoted(true), portrayed(true), max_depth(0)]).
```